# Why does this add up to 11 and not 8?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm studying for intro comp sci test tomorrow and need to be able to determine the value of different operations. With my calculations t should be equal to 8. But when compiling it returns 11. Why does it run the second if? 2 is not greater than 3. I know it's probably just a misunderstanding problem but it would really help out. 
Thanks in advance.

```
public class Prac {     
    public static void main(String []args){
        int i=4, j=3, k=10;
        float r=3, s=2, t=5;
        boolean done = false;

        if (s*2 >= j && t >= s) {
            if (s>j)
                s++;
            t = t * s;
        } else
            t += s;
        t++;
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer condition is true and the inner condition is false.

Therefore the statements executed are:

```
t = t * s; // 5 * 2 == 10
```

and

```
t++; // 11
```

The code would be clearer with the proper indentation and curly braces:

```
    if (s*2 >= j && t >= s) { // 2 * 2 >= 3 && 5 >= 2 - true
        if (s>j) { // 2 > 3 - false
            s++; // not executed
        }
        t = t * s; // executed
    } else {
        t += s; // not executed
    }
    t++; // executed
```

Comment: Good answer, but as long as the indentation is correct (any IDE can do this for you), curly braces don’t make the code more clear IMHO.

Comment: @Bohemian I guess that's a matter of opinion. I find it painful to the eye when the if clause has curly braces and the else clause doesn't (or vice versa).

Comment: I understand now, I thought that it had to execute the s++; before the t = t*s;. Thank you for your help.